# Loop is not catching duplicates and removing them in Android(Java)

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist, duplicates

I've recently started programming in Android and Java in general so please bear with me.

I wrote a loop that should, before adding a new name and phone number to a list and hidden array, remove any duplicates it finds right before. Using the current methods I still get constant repeats, and when clicking the button to add all the same contacts again, I get all the contacts again. This makes me think the duplicate check method isn't working correctly at all, but Im not getting any erors to help

I have two list arrays that I created outside:

```
List<String> phnnumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is the Adding contacts method:

```
 public void AddAllContacts(View view) {
    try {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String linesp = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbersview);
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            duplicatecheck(name, phoneNumber);
            addthistothelist(name, phoneNumber);
        }
        phones.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the duplicate check method:

```
public void duplicatecheck(String name,String phoneNumber) {
    for (int i=0;i<phnnumbers.size();i++) {
        String thenumber = phnnumbers.get(i);
        String thename= names.get(i);
    if(thenumber.equals(phoneNumber)) {
            phnnumbers.remove(i);
            names.remove(i);
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbersview);
        String textpost = quantityTextView.getText().toString();
        String newtextpost = textpost.replaceAll(thenumber, "UNBELIEVABLEEE");
        String secondtextpost = newtextpost.replaceAll(thename, "UNBELIEVABLE");
        quantityTextView.setText(secondtextpost);
        NumberOfContactsAdded--;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method that gets called after it should check for duplicates and remove, this next method is the one adding the number and name next:

```
public void addthistothelist(String nameofperson,String NumberOfPerson) {

    String linesp = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbersview);
    String textpost = quantityTextView.getText().toString();
    NumberOfPerson = NumberOfPerson.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    if(NumberOfPerson.contains("+1")) {
        phnnumbers.add(NumberOfPerson);
        names.add(nameofperson);
        NumberOfContactsAdded++;
        quantityTextView.append(linesp+nameofperson+" " +NumberOfPerson);
    } else  {
        NumberOfPerson= "+1"+NumberOfPerson;
        phnnumbers.add(NumberOfPerson);
        names.add(nameofperson);
        NumberOfContactsAdded++;
        quantityTextView.append(linesp+nameofperson+" " +NumberOfPerson);
    }
}
```

Im really lost on what I could be doing wrong. I would attempt to clean up this code but its not even working properly for me to clean it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can do like this:

1. Create a bean class for person

   public class Person {
       private String name;
       private String phone;

   ```
   public Person(String name, String phone) {
       this.name = name;
       phone = phone.replaceAll("\\W+", "");
       phone = "+1"+phone;
       this.phone = phone;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o)
           return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
           return false;
       Person person = (Person) o;
       return name != null ? name.equals(person.name) : person.name == null && (phone != null ? phone.equals(person.phone) : person.phone == null);

   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
       result = 31 * result + (phone != null ? phone.hashCode() : 0);
       return result;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Then iterate all the contacts and put them in a set, it will automatically avoid dulicates

   ```
   Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<>();

   public void AddAllContacts(View view) {
       try {
           Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

       while (phones.moveToNext()) {
           String linesp = System.getProperty("line.separator");
           TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbersview);
           String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
           String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
           Person person = new Person(name, phoneNumber);
           persons.add(person);
       }
       phones.close();
   ```

   **// here what you want you can do with Person's Set**
           }
           catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

Comment: Okay that makes sense. How would I grab each person's name and phone number in a different string? Im trying to make them loop through each based on the size of the Hashset. Since I will use a c ommand that needs their name and number seperated. I cant use person.name or person.phoneNumber in another method

Comment: Once you had the set of persons, then you iterate this set, get each Person object and then give this Person object to another method.

Comment: Im sorry Im not sure how I would do that? `Iterator<String> it = hset.iterator();
     while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
     }` Thats how to iterate but how would I give it to another method or change it to a different type?

Comment: `for (String person : persons) {
            System.out.println("name = " + person.getName+", phone = "+person.getPhone());
        }`

Comment: Im still not seeing how I can use this for what Im trying to do. Im trying to use a loop the size of the amount of Names in that array, going through each and  running `sms.sendTextMessage(NumberOfPerson, null, Message, null, null);` Using the number of that specific name in the Message somewhere. getName() and getPhone gives me errors even when I made a method that returns name/phone as a string. Im sorry Ive never used iterators or Hashsets before

Comment: Why you get error, iteration of set is sample enough `for (Person person : persons) { if(person.getName.equals("MyfavoriteName")) {sendMessage(person.getPhone, null, Message, )} }`, The Person class must have getter and setter.

Comment: Using this it was just an infinite loop, sending millions of messages to the numbers stored: http://paste.ofcode.org/cytLMBFiQs6bSvX6kEL8zx

Comment: You can control the loop, if you not control it definitely it will send message to the contacts which is stored in the set.

Comment: Could you take a look at that link? Im not sure how to control this loop as I don't understand how to control sets at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98071/discussion-between-bahramdun-adil-and-projoh).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience of programming with android, but one thing I can see is that you are removing elements from phnnumbers whilst you are iterating through phnnumbers, you should not do this. Either use an iterator, or add the elements/element indexes to a list, and remove them from phnnumbers after iterating through phnnumbers.

Comment: I think my problem doesn't have much to do with Android, just java itself. So could I solve that by putting a new variable equal to the size of phnnumbers before I start going through it, and using that rather than its .size() or would that not work?

Comment: It's bad to remove variables as you iterate through a collection, with the for (int i.... Approach i know with arraylists that you will skip an element after you remove it. The object in index i will be a new object after you call remove (i), but then you continue with the loop, and this new element is skipped. For other collections the behaviour will vary, so for future reference it would be best to use an iterator's remove method, or "remember" indexes/objects to remove, and remove them after you have finished iterating